# How many @ need to be used when I try to use apply function?

Tags: functions, notation, head

According to the manual, $f@@A$ means apply function $f$ to $A$. If it would be the same if I only use one @? Does $f@A$ still represent apply apply function $f$ to $A$? And it would help a lot if someone know a way to transform a general polynomial $a+b+c*d$ into a list $ \{a,b,c*d\}$ .

**How does one make sense of the use of `@`, `@@` or `@@@`**

Comment: No, this are not equivalent operators. Compare ``f@{1, 2, 3} (* f[{1, 2, 3}] *)`` and ``f@@{1, 2, 3} (* f[1, 2, 3] *)``.

Comment: `a+b+c*d/.Plus:>List`

Comment: Use three to `Map` the `Apply`, e.g., `f @@@ {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}` evaluates to `{f[a, b], f[c, d], f[e, f]}`

Comment: Thank you guys!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, what the documentation says is that in Wolfram Language [Everything is an Expresion](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/language/tutorial/Expressions.html)

[image]

and expression can be written in many forms, one being the [`Prefix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prefix.html) form

[image]

The prefix form `f@g` wraps the [`Head`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) `f` around the expression `g`.

`f@@g` is the Infix form of the [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) function, that replaces the outermost [`Head`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) of the expression `g` with `f`. `@@` should be considered a single operator and is not two consecutive instances of `@`.

[image]

Check for instance

[image]

For the expression you care, check the internal representation

[image]

So you want to *replace* the Head "[`Plus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus.html)" for [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html), that could be achieved in more than one way...

Replacing the head with [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) or with [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
Apply[List,a+b+c*d]
ReplaceAll[a+b+c*d, Plus->List]
```

or in their shorted form

```
List@@(a+b+c*d)
(a+b+c*d)/.Plus->List
```

So `@` adds a Head, but `@@` replaces a Head at level 0, `@@@` replaces a Head at level 1.

Now if you have a list of expressions, then you will need to [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) at a higher level, for example at level 1 instead of zero using `@@@`.

```
List@@@{a+b+c*d, e+f+g*h}
```

> ```
> {{a,b,c d},{e,f,g h}}
> ```

Answer (score 8):

In Mathematica, Expr all have `Head`, you can use `expr // Head` to see it.

for something like

```
head[body]
```

f@@ means

```
f[body]
```

f@ means

```
f[head[body]]
```

---

so, convert `a+b+c*d` to list

```
Plus[a,b,Times[c,d]]
```

to

```
List[a,b,Times[c,d]]
```

```
List@@(a+b+c*d)
```

Or replace it. `a+b+c*d/.Plus:>List`

Comment: Why not `Plus -> List`?

Comment: It might be valuable to explain what `@@@` does as well, and how it differs from `@` and `@@`.