# Extracting variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, polynomials, variable

Similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21257/extracting-variables-from-an-expression) perhaps, but I prefer a built-in function.

I have defined the expression `L = a*b*c`.

Is there a Mathematica function that can identify and extract the variables (e.g., in the multiplication shown). I guess it could also apply to other functions, not only `Times[]`) and return them in a list?

It would have to return `{a,b,c}` in the case above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try: `Variables[L]`

Comment: That is great, I didn't know Variables[] had that usage. Thanks!

Comment: In this case, as well as if you have `L=a+b+c` you can make `List@@L`

Comment: For the factors use `List@@L`. For more complicated expressions to find all variables use `Variables[Level[L, {-1}]]`

Comment: Similar problem https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/255614/10397